# PL/SQL Trigger to return out of stock error: Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have the following tables:

```
order_lines table
    Name  Null?  Type  
    ORDER_ID  NOT NULL  NUMBER(5)  
    PRODUCT_ID  NOT NULL  NUMBER(4)  
    ACTUAL_PRICE     NUMBER  
    DISCOUNT     NUMBER  
    QUANTITY     NUMBER  
    TOTAL_AMOUNT     NUMBER
```

And

```
Product_inventory table
Name  Null?  Type  
PRODUCT_ID  NOT NULL  NUMBER(4)  
QTY_ON_HAND     NUMBER  
QTY_ON_ORDER     NUMBER  
DATE_ORDERED     DATE  
DELIVERY_DATE     DATE
```

I'm trying to have a trigger that checks the quantity of order and see if it was out of stock, and display a message if it was. My current trigger is compiling with some errors:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_order_line  
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON order_lines
  for each row
DECLARE
  l_current_stock product_inventory.qty_on_hand%type;
BEGIN 
  select product_inventory.qty_on_hand
    into l_current_stock
    from product_inventory, order_lines
   where product_inventory.product_id = :new.product_id;
  if(:new.quantity > l_current_stock) then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Insufficient Stock');
  else
    update product_inventory
   set qty_on_hand = qty_on_hand - :new.quantity
 where product_inventory.product_id = :new.product_id;
  end if;
END;
```

When I'm testing the trigger I'm getting the following errors:

```
 insert into order_lines values (388,1023,100,20,2,160)
            *

ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows 
ORA-06512: at "DBA643.CHECK_ORDER_LINE", line 4 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DBA643.CHECK_ORDER_LINE'
```

Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operator in **SQL** is `=`, not `:=` (that's for PL/SQL only). Additionally the *comparison* operator is also `=` and not `:=`

So this statement:

```
update product_inventory
   set qty_on_hand:= qty_on_hand - :new.quantity
 where product_id:= :new.product_id;
```

should be

```
update product_inventory
   set qty_on_hand = qty_on_hand - :new.quantity
 where product_id = :new.product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you the trigger is working fine but when I'm trying to test the trigger it's giving me errors.. I have updated the post

Comment: @WT86: you are creating a cross join with this line: `from product_inventory, order_lines` remove the `order_lines` table from the select statement. It's not needed there. And make sure that `select` returns only a single row (as indicated by the error message)

Comment: @WT86: and it's usually not a good idea to change the question with a totally new error. You should rather create a new question for that problem (the original problem has been solved)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I' getting the message that I added in the trigger but I'm getting two more errors
ORA-06512: at "DBA643.CHECK_ORDER_LINE", line 9 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DBA643.CHECK_ORDER_LINE'

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is not multi-user safe. As users can select from the table and not see other users uncommitted changes they could believe there is enough stock when in fact, when the other users commit their changes, there will not be. This could result in the `qty_on_hand` becoming negative. You need to make the check and update an atomic process.

Additionally, you are not handling changes in the quantity correctly in an update, and have not considered what should happen if `order_lines` are deleted (although there may be other validation that prevent this), and hence a quantity is removed.

One option would be to `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` to prevent other users even looking at the current total until this user has finished and committed/rolled back any changes e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_order_line  
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON order_lines
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_quantity_change product_inventory.qty_on_hand%TYPE;
  l_current_stock   product_inventory.qty_on_hand%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  IF INSERTING THEN
    l_quantity_change := :new.quantity;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    l_quantity_change :=
      CASE
        WHEN :new.quantity IS NOT NULL AND :old.quantity IS NOT NULL THEN
          :new.quantity - :old.quantity
        WHEN :new.quantity IS NOT NULL THEN
          :new.quantity
        WHEN :old.quantity IS NOT NULL THEN
          -:old.quantity
        ELSE
          NULL
      END;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    l_quantity_change := -:old.quantity;
  END IF;
  IF l_quantity_change IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT qty_on_hand
      INTO l_current_stock
      FROM product_inventory
     WHERE product_id = :new.product_id
       FOR UPDATE OF qty_on_hand;
    IF l_current_stock IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF l_quantity_change > l_current_stock THEN
        raise_application_error(-20103, 'Insufficient Stock');
      ELSE
        UPDATE product_inventory
           SET qty_on_hand = qty_on_hand - l_quantity_change
         WHERE product_id = :new.product_id;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Another option would be to add a check constraint to the `product_inventory` table to ensure that the `qty_on_hand` cannot be negative. This would cause a check constraint violation error if the value was less than zero e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE product_inventory
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_qty_on_hand
  CHECK (qty_on_hand IS NULL OR qty_on_hand >= 0)

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_order_line  
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON order_lines
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_quantity_change product_inventory.qty_on_hand%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  IF INSERTING THEN
    l_quantity_change := :new.quantity;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    l_quantity_change :=
      CASE
        WHEN :new.quantity IS NOT NULL AND :old.quantity IS NOT NULL THEN
          :new.quantity - :old.quantity
        WHEN :new.quantity IS NOT NULL THEN
          :new.quantity
        WHEN :old.quantity IS NOT NULL THEN
          -:old.quantity
        ELSE
          NULL
      END;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    l_quantity_change := -:old.quantity;
  END IF;
  IF l_quantity_change IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE product_inventory
       SET qty_on_hand = qty_on_hand - l_quantity_change
     WHERE product_id = :new.product_id
       AND qty_on_hand IS NOT NULL;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: thank you so much. But I don't need it to be that specific, does my Trigger do what I'm asking for?

Comment: If you wish the trigger to **guarantee** that an order cannot be placed if there is not sufficient stock to satisfy it and an order can be placed/amended if there is sufficient stock to satisfy it then your trigger does not meet these requirements. Orders may be being placed at the same time which may be individually allowed to progress but when finished will result in a negative `qty_on_hand`.